# Rails acts_as_tenant seed data

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using the `gem 'acts_as_tenant'` in a Rails 3 project.

I would like to seed new data every time a new Tenant is added - but only for the new Tenant.

Is there a way to pass a variable to `rake db:seed`?

Something like:

```
rake db:seed -tenant=5
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked:

```
$ TENANT=5 rake db:seed
```

In seed.rb:

```
statuscode = Statuscode.first_or_create(
    :tenant_id => ENV['TENANT'],
    :statuscode => 'Completed',
    :closed => true
)
```